# php in_array giving odd result

Tags: php, arrays

I've read all the other articles on in_array, and still don't understand why mine is givng odd results.  I'm inheriting this code from someone else, and don't fully understand why they did certain things. When a user logs in, data is grabbed from a db, one of the fields being their "level".  1 is an admin, 2 a regular user, etc.  Once the data is grabbed from the db, we put the user level (stored as a:1:{i:0;s:1:"2") into an array:

```
$user_level = unserialize($this->result['user_level']); 
$_SESSION['unt']['user_level'] = $user_level;
```

Later we check to see if this is an admin:

```
error_log(print_r($_SESSION['abc']['user_level']));  //this is always "1"
if (in_array('1', $_SESSION['abc']['user_level'])) {   //should be yes, correct?
```

Yet somehow the if statement never evaluates as true, even though the SESSION variable is 1. What am I missing?

Comment: Your print_r should have true as the second parameter if you are passing the result instead of printing it e.g. error_log(print_r($_SESSION['abc']['user_level'], true));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I noticed closing bracket `}` missing from your input string I just assumed that you probably might have missed while copy-pasting .

```
a:1:{i:0;s:1:"2"
```

So `in_array` is not the problem but your input string is the problem .
With `display_errors` setting `Off` you would not see any error when you try to `unserialize` it .

> You could use the below function to check if the input is a valid string to unserialize :

```
//  Copied from http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php
function is_serialized( $str )
{
    return( $str == serialize( false ) || @unserialize( $str ) !== false );
}
```

Then something along these lines :

```
    $inputString = 'a:1:{i:0;s:1:"2";}';   //  Is valid and is holding one array of info
//  $inputString = 'a:1:{i:0;s:1:"2"';   //  Invalid as is missing a closing baracket }

if( ! is_serialized( $inputString ) )
{
    echo 'Is not serialized';
}
else
{
    $user_level = unserialize( $inputString );

    $_SESSION['unt']['user_level'] = $user_level;   //  Is an array

//  Note the second argument as was already pointed by @AsksAnyway
    error_log( print_r( $_SESSION['unt']['user_level'] , true ) );

    var_dump( in_array( '1' ,$_SESSION['unt']['user_level']) );

    var_dump( in_array( '2' ,$_SESSION['unt']['user_level']) );
}
```

Comment: Interesting.  So even though gettype says it's an array, print_r prints only the number 1.  Both var_dumps come back as NULL.

Comment: Your serialized string is missing ending curly bracket `}` : `a:1:{i:0;s:1:"2"` and it seems that you turned `Off` `display_errors` . In that scenario , I too got the same result : `1` , `null` , `null` . If the `display_errors` is `On` PHP would have failed while `unserialize`ing . I have updated my answer accordingly .

Comment: I missed the ending curly bracket when I cut and pasted, and turned on display_errors.  The solution from Uours worked like a charm - thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`$_SESSION['abc']['user_level']` doesn't appear to be an array. Looks like you want one of the following.

If gettype($_SESSION['abc']['user_level']) is 'integer':

```
if ($_SESSION['abc']['user_level']) === 1) {
```

If gettype($_SESSION['abc']['user_level']) is 'string':

```
if ($_SESSION['abc']['user_level']) === '1') {
```

If gettype($_SESSION['abc']['user_level']) is 'string' and its value actually contains the quotes:

```
if ($_SESSION['abc']['user_level']) === '"1"') {
```

If it was an array the output would have this structure, not just "1":

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
)
```

Comment: Interesting - when I use gettype, it comes back as an array, so none of the above work!